# Scatterplot with 2 y-axis in R

Tags: r, plot, scatter-plot

I have the following data in my dataset named "px"

| anneemut | valeurfonc | sbati |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2014 | 696300 | 321.5 |
| 2015 | 426600 | 144.5 |
| 2016 | 510000 | 163.0 |

And some other years.

I'd like to plot this 3 variables in the same chart. I thought about a scatter plot, with y1 = anneemut and y2 = sbati.

I found this code online :

```
par(mar = c(5, 4, 4, 4) + 0.3)   # Additional space for second y-axis
plot(px$valeurfonc, px$anneemut, pch = 16, col = 2)              

# Create first plot
par(new = TRUE)                 # Add new plot
plot(px$anneemut, px$sbati, pch = 17, col = 3,  

# Create second plot without axes
     axes = FALSE, xlab = "", ylab = "")
axis(side = 4, at = pretty(range(px$sbati)))      
# Add second axis
mtext("Avg_surface", side = 4, line = 3)
```

Here is the output [image]

I cannot manage to change the name of my axis. I tried to do

```
# Create second plot without axes
     axes = FALSE, xlab = "Price", ylab = "Year")
```

But the initial names don't disappear and then we can't read anything.

Furthermore, I cannot manage to add all the year in the first y axis, and all the values, in full number, in the x-axis.

Is there a way to do this in ggplot for instance ?

Comment: your plot as two different x-axes and two different y-axes. the labels are cut off because the plot is too small or the text would be overlapping, increase the size of the plot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```r
px <- data.frame(anneemut = c(2014, 2015, 2016),
                 valuerfonc = c(696300, 426600, 510000),
                 sbati = c(321.5, 144.5, 163.0))

par(mar = c(5, 4, 4, 4) + 0.3)              
plot(px$valuerfonc, px$anneemut, xlab = "valuerfonc", ylab = "anneemut", pch = 16, col = 2)              
par(new = TRUE)                             
plot(px$valuerfonc, px$sbati, pch = 17, col = 3,              
     axes = FALSE, xlab = "", ylab = "")
axis(side = 4, at = pretty(range(px$sbati)))      
mtext("sbati", side = 4, line = 3)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-07-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>